# File.ReadLines and convert type error

Tags: c#, file

Using the `System.IO;` and then using this code to write in a Txt file.

```
        Text.Text = File.ReadLines(Path.Text, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Path.Text is the name of a TextBox which contains the the path of the file.
The error is:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'
```

Comment: Try `File.ReadAllText`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines(Path.Text, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Note that `File.ReadLines()` returns an object of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String>`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are trying to assign a value that is a collections of strings (`IEnumerable<string>`) to a property that is a string (`Text`).

Use this:

```
Text.Text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Text, Encoding.Unicode)
```

`ReadAllText` returns the entire file contents as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadLines()` returns an object of type  `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String>`. 
`File.ReadAllLines()` returns an array of strings.

If you want to use an array of strings you need to call the correct function.

for Easy solution, just use `ReadAllLines()` or you could change your return type.

This would also work:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt");
```

You can use any generic collection which implements IEnumerable. IList for an example.